# Best way to create a "Real Time" table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

So, I have a **NStimer** loop in my app that is constantly surveying the surroundings searching for bluetooth devices.

Whenever a device is discovered I want to update the table view to include a cell with that device info.

Can I fake a table view using a **UIScrollView** and add/remove the info cell accordingly at every run of the loop?!

Or should I use a **UITableView** and the reloadData method?

Assuming we'll only have max. 5 items/cells at same table.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only ever going to have 5 rows in the table, just use a `UITableView` and call `-reloadData`. Don't use a `UIScrollView` and re-invent the table view. The table view is pretty efficient as it is.

Also, if you know which row you want to update you can even be more efficient and reload *only* that row:

`-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`